# How to modify my angular app URL and include a sub path?

Tags: angular, redirect, routes

I'm using angular 10, so far, the URL of my app is : `mycoolapp.com/` but now, I need to have it : `mycooleapp.com/firstApp/` because I'm workin on a reverse proxy and will need to create a new app having the same domain `mycoolapp.com` the difference will be after the domain (firstApp, and secondApp)

How can I make it ? (to add a base href ?)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `--base-href` option with `ng build` like the following:

```
ng build --base-href /firstApp/
```

Comment: Thank you, should I just run this line or add it in angular.json file ?

Comment: No, it depends on how you are deploying your app to the server.
If you're deploying it by transferring dist files manually to the server, then you can run this command to generate the dist files.